# cannot Add custom fields to user model on login via next auth in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js, next-auth

i need to add custom fields to default user model when user logs in via next auth. i tried the method in official documentation https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/typeorm-custom-models.

following is my code:

models/User.js

```
import Adapters from "next-auth/adapters";

export default class User extends Adapters.TypeORM.Models.User.model {
    constructor(name, email, image, emailVerified) {
    super(name, email, image, emailVerified);
         }
}

export const UserSchema = {
  name: "User",
  target: User,
  columns: {
    ...Adapters.TypeORM.Models.User.schema.columns,
    // Adds a phoneNumber to the User schema
    phoneNumber: {
      type: "varchar",
      nullable: false,
      default: "test",
    },
  },
};
```

models/index.js

```
import User, { UserSchema } from "./User";

export default {
  User: {
    model: User,
    schema: UserSchema,
  },
};
```

pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Providers from "next-auth/providers";
import Adapters from "next-auth/adapters";
import Models from "../../../models";

const { MONGODB_URI } = process.env;

export default NextAuth({
  
  providers: [
    Providers.Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
     ],
  adapter: Adapters.TypeORM.Adapter(
       MONGODB_URI,
       {
      models: {
        User: Models.User,
      },
    }
  ),

  });
```

This should have added an additional field of phone number to the user model, but when i check db it only contains the default fields. what am i doing wrong here? is there a better way of achieving the same result??

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a default value to your field.

```
export default class User extends Adapters.TypeORM.Models.User.model {
    customField;
    constructor(name, email, image, emailVerified, customField) {
       super(name, email, image, emailVerified);
       if (customField) this.customField = customField;
    }
}
```

Comment: it was getting frustrating for me due to lack of documentation on this issue by next auth. so i changed my code and switched to passport instead. as for your answer i had already tried this. It wasn't working.